# Need help sorting table with an aggregate function

Tags: sql

I am trying to get this table to display book num, book title, and the number of times each book was checked out (even if it was never checked out.)

The current output I get is correct, but I want to sort it by book num and "Times Checked Out".

```
SELECT book.book_num
  ,book_title
  ,Count(checkout.book_num) AS "Times Checked Out"
FROM checkout right join book ON checkout.book_num = book.book_num
GROUP BY book.book_num, book_title;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use it as inner query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT book.book_num,book_title,Count(checkout.book_num) AS "Times Checked Out"
    FROM checkout right join book ON checkout.book_num = book.book_num
    GROUP BY book.book_num, book_title
) AS foo
ORDER BY "Times Checked Out";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    book.book_num,
    book_title,
    COUNT(checkout.book_num) AS "Times Checked Out"
FROM checkout
RIGHT JOIN book ON checkout.book_num = book.book_num 
GROUP BY
    book.book_num,
    book_title
ORDER BY
    book.book_num,
    COUNT(checkout.book_num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Common Table Expression

```
;WITH BookDetails AS
(
    SELECT book.book_num
          ,book_title
          ,Count(checkout.book_num) AS "TimesCheckedOut"
    FROM checkout right join book ON checkout.book_num = book.book_num
    GROUP BY book.book_num, book_title;
)

SELECT
    book_num
   ,book_title
   ,TimesCheckedOut as 'Times Checked Out'
FROM BookDetails
ORDER BY TimesCheckedOut
```

This is assuming you're not using MySql but instead something like MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it is just set it as a subquery and sort that:

```
SELECT book_num AS "Book Number",
 ,book_title AS "Book Title"
 ,times_checked_out AS "Times Checked Out"
FROM (
    SELECT Book.book_num
      ,Book.book_title
      ,COUNT(Checkout.book_num) AS times_checked_out
    FROM checkout Checkout
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN book Book ON Checkout.book_num = Book.book_num
    GROUP BY Book.book_num, Book.book_title
) Counts
ORDER BY book_num,times_checked_out
```

This will only do the `COUNT` once and provide the ordering you're looking for. It's also ANSI-compliant, so quite performant.